# If "Image name" in database matches "Image Name" in directory, display images in gridview

Tags: android, image, sqlite, gridview

I am new to android and the concepts of programming, I'm a bit stuck on something atm and could do with a push in the right direction.

I am developing an app that has a function allowing users to capture an image, store that image in the app's file system, and store a reference to that image in an sqlite database. I explain this [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20256631/storing-and-retrieving-uri-from-sqlite), and got some good feedback as to how I would go about storing the reference in the database...I chose to just store the **file name** of the image.

The real issue here is that I do not know how to go about **[retrieving the image reference from the database and display the images in a grid view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280605/retrieving-image-references-from-an-sqlite-database-and-displaying-them-in-a-gri)**. The way I think this can work is to have a query something like:

> IF (*image name* in database == *image name* in file system)
>   {
>    Display those images only
>   }

I don't know how to implement this, any help or insight will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this:

retrieve all the image names from the data base and then check if they exists on file system or not.

```
if(new File(FOLDERPATH + File.separator + file_name_in_db).exists()) {
   // add file to list to be set in grid view adapter
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestion. This seems like something that could work. I will try it and see what happens.

Comment: ya sure.. it will definitely work, implemented it recently.. :)
let me know if you need any help..