# How I can store an image from gallery in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, gallery

I want to get an image and store it in sqlite what should I do?

For example user clicks on button and picks an image from gallery now I want to store it in sqlite and show that image on another one activity.

Comment: Storing an actual image in a db is usually not a good idea, you should be putting the path to the image in the database

Comment: So, what should I do?

Comment: you should store the url in your database like I said then get the image when you need it from the url

Comment: Here's an example [How to retrieve a large BLOB from database in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46518604/how-to-retrieve-a-large-blob-from-database-in-android/46519680#46519680).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android Phones due to their nature its not a good idea to store images in the Database since it is not thread safe storing byte to byte of the Images. Also its complicated to pass a Bitmap to another Activity and it can lead to Memory Errors.

It may make your app slow an even get ANR (`Application Not Responding`) errors, So if you want to store Images just store their File `path` to the folder they are found or `Uri` to their location.
You need some training to ways to get `Uri` when guiding user to pick the Image which is not under the scope of this question. So consider visiting [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20256631/storing-and-retrieving-uri-from-sqlite). Also also [this external link](https://afterthoughtsoftware.com/posts/Storing-image-URIs-using-Android-SQLite).